# Python timeout decorator for unit testing on Windows

Tags: python, windows, unit-testing, timeout

I want to have an easy way of testing whether particular method returns within time allotted.

[Timeout decorator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/04/using-python-timeout-decorator-uploading-s3/) looks like the most convenient way of doing that but unfortunately it won't work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440569/) thread-based solution, but as noted [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/714002-cross-platform-time-out-decorator), there's usually no way to kill a thread in Python, so even after the thread "times out" it continues running. However, you can use [this](http://sebulba.wikispaces.com/recipe+thread2) to actually terminate the thread assuming it's not tied up in C-land.

Not a ready-made recipe, unfortunately, but it looks like it has all the parts you need.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why the Timeout Decorator won't work on windows?

If this is permanent, and not just for debugging purposes you could use a [for else](http://psung.blogspot.com/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html) loop inside the method.

```
def methodName(timeout):
   for i in range(timout):
       if done_doing_task:
           break
   else: #will only be executed if we don't break out of the for loop
       raise Exception('method methodName timed out')
```

Comment: If you check the doc for the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module, you'll see that `signal.alarm()` (which is used by the timeout decorator) is listed as UNIX-only.